# String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. Asp.net

Tags: database, asp.net-core

[I am getting this error in spite of declaring every column datatype  to max](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KXjw.png)

[This is my code I'm just logging my exceptions to the db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlTaD.png)

[Desgin of my table,(I use ssms 2014)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaRRu.png)

Comment: Please upload code in text instead in images. Images can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers, harder to read than text.

Comment: How large is your input data? For reference, the maximum for varchar(max) is 2 GB: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.